# does the Timer class effect that mush of app performance?

Tags: flutter, dart

i have the following timer which repeat it's self every single second

```
Timer? myTimer ;
String myString = '';

void myChick(){
    myTimer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (_) {
      if(myString.isNotEmpty ){
        myString = '';
        // here i am doing very simple work like change some of variblse 
       }
    });
}
```

Note: i am not close `myTimer` never and it keep repeat its self as long as user use my app

now my question does it effect too mush of my app performance ?

Comment: You can check the performance of your app while using it if you are using android studio or vs code like this. You can check Flutter inspector. There you can check Performance view, CPU Profiler view, Memory view etc

Comment: Do this while using your flutter app and check how it affects your performance

Comment: thank for remind me that , i really don't know how could i forget something like this

Comment: if you found the comment useful dont mind upvoting it

Comment: Use the profiler to find out deterministically how does it tax your application. The question is also not precise, what could someone answer? "yes", "no", "just "use a profiler"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a profiler and find out determiniscaly for your use case how does tax your application, but it will depend more on your overall architecture than on the timer itself.

```
flutter run --profile
```

Watch [any video online](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZfSiFtT0z_I) if you need to learn how does it work: